# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in koa2 & nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, koa

I try to return a json string, and some codes like this

```
.post('/reqwords', async (ctx) => {
let goroClient = new GOROClient()
goroClient.send({
    //some codes
}).then(function (res) {
    let {Code}=res;
    if (Code === 'OK') {
        console.log(res);
        ctx.body = res;
    }
 }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    ctx.body = err;
 })
})
```

And it shows the error information `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, any ideas?

Comment: Where are you logging value for `thebody`? Your question is little unclear.

Comment: @Raeesaa I want to pass the `res` or `err` to `ctx.body`, if I change `if (Code === 'OK') {
        console.log(res)
        thebody = res
    }` to `if (Code === 'OK') {
        console.log(res)
        ctx.body = res
    }`, that is not right, so I use `thebody` to pass, but it seems not work.

Comment: @Raeesaa I updated the code, and now i might be clear.

Comment: This is a 404 error which means you have either not defined endpoint `/reqwords` correctly or there is some mistake in API call being made from client.

Comment: @Raeesaa the above code is all in `/reqwords`, if I add `ctx.body` above `})`, it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `goroClient.send({` to `await goroClient.send({`, that works.